# How to find what day of the week for any given date using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to figure out what day (i.e. Monday, Friday...) of any given date (i.e. Jun 27th, 2009)

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to distinguish the difference between Objective-C and Cocoa. It is perfectly feasible to use one without the other, but in the case of dates I assume you are talking about Cocoa.

Comment: While they are distinct entities, it's arguably easier to use Objective-C without Cocoa than vice-versa. Even if they were to use Cocoa from Python or whatever, the classes and method calls would be exactly the same. Also, the "objective-c" tag is not near as active as Java or C#, and pretty much everyone who is viewing this tag is interested in Mac or iPhone programming.

Comment: Did you read the unedited question? It did not make any reference to Cocoa, hence the edit and comment. I think it is important to make the distinction, just as people should with C++ and STL, C# and .NET, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I saw it before it was edited, (is there a way to view revisions of a question?), and I can understand that the answer to his question is Cocoa-specific. However, I'd guess that > 95% of Cocoa devs are using Objective-C, and > 99% of all Objective-C devs are using Cocoa (as opposed to GNUstep, etc.). The two tags are very closely related, and I didn't figure that tagging with Objective-C would anger fans of the language that don't use Cocoa. If I'm totally wrong on that count, I have no problem with removing the Objective-C tag. :-)

Comment: It was the title of the question, not the tags. The objective-c and cocoa tags are very fitting for the question, but before, without any reference to Cocoa, I could have provided a POSIX solution and it would have fit the criteria of the question. Most Cocoa developers are using Objective-C and most Objective-C developers are using Cocoa but that's no reason use the two terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 28):

I've been doing:

```
NSDateFormatter* theDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[theDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *weekDay =  [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This has the added bonus of letting you choose how you'd like the weekday to be returned (by changing the date format string in the setDateFormat: call

Lots more information at:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369

Answer (score 16):

You may have a look to the NSDate and NSCalendar classes.
For example, [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCalendar) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW2)

They provide the following code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
                [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
NSInteger day = [weekdayComponents day];
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Answer (score 6):

Use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents. As shown in the NSDateComponents documentation:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
int weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Comment: Where is "comps" coming from? Also, technically @ThisThib is correct that -weekday returns an NSInteger value. Shouldn't be a problem for any calendar I know, but in the name of correctness and portability...  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I wound up with, which works exactly as intended.  It takes a date, alters the date to be the first of the month, and gets the *day* of that date:

```
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];
NSDateComponents *monthDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear |
                                         NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate: date];

//  build date as start of month
monthDateComponents.year = components.year;
monthDateComponents.month = components.month;
monthDateComponents.day = 1;

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
//    [gregorian setFirstWeekday:1];

NSDate *builtDate =[gregorian dateFromComponents: monthDateComponents];
//    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components: NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate: builtDate];

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"E"];

NSString *firstDay = [df stringFromDate:builtDate];
if([firstDay isEqual:@"Sun"])  //  do for the other 6 days as appropriate
    return 7;
```