# How to get a date for a day in current week

Tags: iphone

i need to set alarm for monday , Saturday ,friday etc... on every week repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following link for your answer.

[How to find what day of the week for any given date using Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057349/how-to-find-what-day-of-the-week-for-any-given-date-using-cocoa)

Just need to do some stuff. It returns opposite of what you need so accordingly you can do some stuff to get what you required.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Happy to have your problem resolved. If the answer was useful you should accept it using the √ symbol to its left. Happy Coding. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NSDate Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).