# Day of the week in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the day of the week in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-in-objective-c)

How do I print the day of the week? What object should I use? I need the day (e.g. Sunday, Thursday), not the date in the month.

Update:
Specifically: how can I find the *number* of the day of the week (e.g. 1, 5)

Comment: I'm actually looking for the *number* of the day of the week

Comment: Then _why_ did you say "e.g. Sunday, Thursday"? How to get the index is pretty easy to figure out from [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html), and [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1057405/603977) also tells you how.

Answer (score 8):

Make an instance of NSDate (for right now, use `[NSDate date]`), and then use an NSDateFormatter and a format string as described [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"]; // day, like "Saturday"
[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"c"]; // day number, like 7 for saturday

NSString *dayOfWeek = [myFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"Today is: %@", dayOfWeek);
```

Comment: Actually I'm looking for the number of the day.. just updated. thanks

Comment: Well, I also showed you interface that is only OS X... my updated answer gets you your number *and* it's available on iOS.